# Loop over list and evaluate element property in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a list with shell lines that I want to execute on inventory hosts so I can determine if the database is working. For the test purposes I have 1 server with PostgreSQL and 1 with MySQL.
This is my playbook so far:

```
    - name: Check db statuses
      shell: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - ps -fp $(pgrep -u postgres) | grep /usr/lib/postgresql
        - ps -fp $(pgrep -u mysql) | grep mysqld
      register: http
      ignore_errors: yes
      changed_when: item.failed == false
```

this is failing with:

```
 {
    "http": {
        "failed": true,
        "msg": "The conditional check 'item.failed == false' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item.failed == false): 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode object' has no attribute 'failed'"
    }
}
```

I want to assign only the `item.failed==false` result in the register variable (`http`)  but ignore the failed ones.

Comment: What is the expected result? [edit] the question and make it [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You can't select what will be registered in a loop. Instead, you'll have to evaluate the registered results in the next task(s), e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - command: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - /bin/true
        - /bin/false
      register: http
      ignore_errors: true

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.item }} failed: {{ item.failed }}"
      loop: "{{ http.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.cmd }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=['/bin/true']) => 
  msg: '/bin/true failed: False'

ok: [localhost] => (item=['/bin/false']) => 
  msg: '/bin/false failed: True'
```